# How does subscription.request(n) in Flow API perform backpressure at any n value?

Tags: java, concurrency, rx-java, reactive-programming, backpressure

I'm playing around with the Flow API and, so far, I understand that the `request()` method is used for back pressure. Most articles state that this is akin to controlling the speed of consumption.

However, almost every example code I see passes the value `1` into the `request()` method, like, `subscription.request(1)`. But I don't quite understand how does the `request()` method control the speed of consumption.

I have tried to run a test by sending a bunch of items to the publisher and print the thread name and it seems like every single `onNext()` is running on the same worker thread be it I was using `request(1)` or `request(50)` :

```
@Override
public void onNext(T item) {
   System.out.println(Thread.getCurrent().getName());
   Thread.sleep(5000);
   subscription.request(50);
}
```

If the `onNext()` were running in different threads, I can understand how that the `n` value passed into `request(n)` will affect the rate at which the items are being processed in parallel (running in `n` threads). But it doesn't seem to be the case in my test as they are all running under the same thread name.

In this case, what's the difference between `request(1)` and `request(50)` when they are all still going to be run sequentially one after another on the same thread? Wouldn't the consumption rate still be the same then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `n` in `request` indicates how many elements the subscriber can accept and gives a limit on how many items the upstream `Publisher` can emit. Therefore, the slowing down of this generator is not per individual item but the average time for each batch generated interleaved by the consumer's processing time.

`onNext` is executed in a serialized fashion and depending on the upstream, on the same thread as well. Thus, calling `request` in there usually indicates the upstream it can call the same `onNext`, **after the current call has ended**, with the next value if available. I.e., calling `Thread.sleep` will postpone this next invocation of `onNext`.

Generally, there is no reason to call `request` in `onNext` an end-Subscriber because it is run synchronously with respect to its immediate upstream `Publisher` and there is no practical difference between a single `request(Long.MAX_VALUE)` and repeated `request(1)`.

One of the few reasons to call `request` if the `onNext` forks off asynchronous work itself and only at the end of that work should more items be requested:

```java
Executor executor = ...

Subscription upstream;

@Override public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
    this.upstream = s;
    executor.execute(() -> {
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       s.request(1);
       return null; // Callable
    });
}

@Override public void onNext(T item) {
    System.out.println("Start onNext");
    executor.execute(() -> {
       System.out.println("Run work");
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       System.out.println("Request more work");
       upstream.request(1);
       return null; // Callable
    });
    System.out.println("End onNext");
}
```

With this setup, the upstream will call `onNext` once and will call it only when the task executed by the executor has issued the next request. Note though that unless the `Publisher` emits from a dedicated thread, the example above will eventually drag the `onNext` invocation onto the `executor`'s thread.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little not sure about the last line. Would you mind elaborating the last line a little more? "_Note though that unless the Publisher emits from a dedicated thread, the example above will eventually drag the onNext invocation onto the executor's thread._"

Comment: "_Generally, there is no reason to call request in onNext an end-Subscriber because it is run synchronously with respect to its immediate upstream Publisher and there is no practical difference between a single request(Long.MAX_VALUE) and repeated request(1)._"
To clarify, so having `request(1)` or `request(50)` doesn't make any difference? Also, you said there is no reason to call `request()` in onNext. But if I don't call `request()`, it doesn't pull the next element from the subscription.

Comment: Many Publishers call `onNext()` in response to `request()` on the same thread. The first of such call may come from the subscriber's thread but subsequent ones may come a different thread. Since `onNext` calls have to be serialized, `request()` calls have to be serialized as well of which the most basic way is to use a queue-drain mechanism for single thread access, which has the property of using the caller thread when it can. It can get more complicated so I recommend watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdSZ6mOQDcY) video series.

Comment: Call `request(Long.MAX_VALUE)` once in `onSubscribe`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I've a better idea of how it works now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Invocations of *onNext()* are not supposed to run in parallel. They can run from different threads (depends on implementation), but always sequentially. But even sequentially, they can be called with higher rate than the subscriber can handle. So subscriber calls *request(n)* only when it has room for n incoming items. Usually it has room for only one value, so it calls *request(1)* when this variable is free.

Comment: What I don't understand though is, if `onNext()` is going to run sequentially one by one, it doesn't have any difference on the rate when we call `request(1)` or `request(50)`, does it? The subscriber will still be clearing the publisher's buffer at a one-by-one rate. It's not like the publisher is going to send the subscriber 50 elements in an array of something, isn't it?

Comment: @Carven request(1) differs from request(50) in that first call allows 1 call of onNext()  and the second allows 50  calls of onNext(). request(1) repeated 50 times does not differ from request(50).